# Abusing meta for hats

Tags: discussion, winterbash

It seems that, right now, even as I'm writing this, somebody is abusing Meta for hats. My own feeling is that this should split the community in two, with half thinking it's just fine and half vehemently against this kind of silliness and [**monkey**ing around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats). People who answer should probably be treated in the same way. *cough*

Comment: Surely five of you think this is abusive enough to downvote? Sheesh. :-)

Comment: DR youve got my downvote. its a pity that humor/ frivolity only comes briefly once a year to SE and then quickly vanishes just like santa claus.

Comment: @vzn Thank you. Much appreciated. :-)

Comment: Thanks to the seven people who indulged me by voting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has outlived its purpose of drawing people to vote on meta.

Answer (score 1):

Meta is serious business and abuse shall not be tolerated.

Are you seriously hoping that 10 different people will vote on a meta post? I wish that would happen more often!

P.S. Pro-skub!

Comment: Yeah, it seems rather optimistic, doesn't it? Especially now that you've made the anti-skub crowd feel unwelcome.